# Changing documentroot in openshift

Tags: python, api, openshift

We're developing an android app with an api backend that we want to deploy via openshift. 
The problem is we have the android app and the webservice in the same github project in two different folders. So I need to change the document_root so that openshift can find the python wsgi.py file.

I've already tried this:

```
rhc env-set OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION="\${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/server/wsgi.py" --app api
```

But then it wouldn't find the requirements.txt because it still uses the wrong document_root.
I tried putting the requirements.txt in the root dir, that way it parses the file but installs the lib's in the wrong place.

I've also tried

```
rhc env-set OPENSHIFT_DOCUMENT_ROOT="\${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/server" --app api
```

But that didn't work either

Help please!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As of the March release of OpenShift online, you can now specify the path to your WSGI with the '`OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION`' environment variable.  You can read more about it here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_PATH
https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-overview.html